# Como alterar o Look and Feel de uma aplicação?

Tags: java, swing

Alguém consegue me explicar como eu faço para mudar o layout das janelas da minha aplicação?

Eu estava montando o aplicativo e testava pelo método `main` normalmente, mas como tomava muito tempo esperar conectar com o servidor e ainda ter que fazer login toda vez que eu quisesse testar uma função, eu criei um método `main` de teste, e quando eu fiz isso tive uma surpresa: o layout estava totalmente diferente... eu não quero arrumar, já que é só iniciar pelo main que fica normal, eu só quero saber se tem como escolher entre outros modelos.

A diferença está nas imagens abaixo:

Esse é o original

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

E esse é como ficou depois:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O formato original usa o look and feel [Nimbus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html), já o formato que ficou depois é o padrão do Java. Você pode selecionar programaticamente o look and feel da sua aplicação da seguinte forma:

```
try {
for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        break;
    }
}
} catch (Exception e) {
   // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
}
```

O loop itera por todos os look and feels suportados e quando encontra o Ninbus seleciona para a sua aplicação. Espero ter ajudado ^^

Comment: Lembrando que essa forma só vai funcionar se for feita antes da EDT ser invocada(ou seja, antes da aplicação abrir). Se fizer depois, a JVM vai escolher o LAF metal, por ser cross plataform. Para alterar em tempo de execução, é da forma como eu mostro [nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150154/28595)

Comment: Tipo, se for o método main responsável por iniciar a frame, fazendo esse laço funciona.

Comment: Foi o que eu disse, só que com outras palavras :)

Comment: Sim, claro. É porque o termo EDT é mais técnico, só quis deixar mais acessível o comentário :P

Comment: Muito obrigado Giuliana, funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 1):

Bem... a pergunta já foi respondida, mas gostaria de acrescentar algo...

Como a Giuliana respondeu e o Roberto acrescentou, esse método funciona quando executado antes da sua aplicação ser iniciada, isto é, antes de ser "criada".

Antes de prosseguir... deixe-me explicar o contexto do meu projeto:

Meu projeto era uma calculadora simples, o qual utiliza JAVA GuiForm para o visual. Nesse projeto, criei uma classe "Calculadora" e um Java Form (usado para criar a interface da aplicação através de uma mecânica semelhante ao Word Press), além da classe principal (Main).

Na classe Calculadora estavam todos os métodos matemáticos básicos, eventos de botões e configurações da aplicação. Enquanto isso, no java Form estava o visual, a parte gráfica, como estilização de botões, cores e etc.

Agora que tudo foi contextualizado, vamos para o problema...

Eu desejava alterar o Look And Feel através de um método dentro da minha classe Calculadora, por um método chamado "inicializar". Na classe main, eu instanciava essa classe e chamava o método mencionado, que por sua vez inicializava a Calculadora e a mostrava.
Ainda que eu chamasse essas configurações do look and feel antes de "subir" o app, o estilo não era aplicado...

Vamos ver isso na prática agora:

```
    /* STARTA O APP */
    public void inicializador(){
        // Tenta alterar o estilo padrão do app        
        try{
            // Varre todos os estilos instalados no dispositivo
            for(UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()){
                // Caso encontre o estilo "nimbus", define-o como padrão desse app e sai do loop
                if("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())){
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){ // Caso não encontre o Nimbus...
            try{
                // Define o look and feel padrão instalado no dispositivo
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException ignored){ // caso não encontre nenhum padrão... ignora
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                // Caso haja algum outro erro de estilo não suportado, 
                // erro de instância ou acesso ilegal mostra um erro
                Logger.getLogger(Integer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "kde lek?", ex);
            }
        }

        setTitle("Calculadora Simples");
        setContentPane(mainPanel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }
```

Como visto acima, o método tenta alterar o estilo antes de ser iniciado. Entretanto isto não funcionará, o por que eu não sei explicar, deixo espaço para que alguém complemente.
Para que esse trecho do Try...Catch funcione, ele precisa ser chamado na classe principal, antes mesmo de criar o objeto de sua classe.

Agora vamos ver como ficaria isso corrigido:

CLASSE PRINCIPAL:

```
    public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        /* TENTA ALTERAR O LOOK AND FEEL DO APP */
        try{
            // Varre todos os estilos instalados no dispositivo
            for(UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()){
                // Caso encontre o estilo "nimbus", define-o como padrão desse app e sai do loop
                if("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())){
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){ // Caso não encontre o Nimbus...
            try{
                // Define o look and feel padrão instalado no dispositivo
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException ignored){ // caso não encontre nenhum padrão... ignora
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                // Caso haja algum outro erro de estilo não suportado,
                // erro de instância ou acesso ilegal mostra um erro
                Logger.getLogger(Integer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "kde lek?", ex);
            }
        }

        // Instancia a calculadora e a inicializa
        TestForm app = new TestForm();
        app.inicializador();
    }
}
```

CLASSE CALCULADORA -> MÉTODO inicializador:

```
/* STARTA O APP */
public void inicializador(){
    setTitle("Calculadora Simples");
    setContentPane(mainPanel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
}
```

E com isso, você se torna capaz de alterar livremente o estilo padrão de tua aplicação.

OBS: Peço desculpas caso tenha me prolongado demais... essa é uma das minhas primeiras respostas no Stack Overflow!