# Como manter o Look And Feel selecionado no JComboBox após a janela ser fechada?

Tags: java, swing

Acabei de criar um simples `JFrame` no NeatBeans com alguns Look And Feel's(LAF) disponíveis, utilizando um `JComboBox` para que o usuário escolha o LAF que desejar, e botei também o botão "Salvar" para Ação.

Consigo mudar o "Tema" perfeitamente. O problema é que o LAF escolhido só é aplicado naquele exato momento da execução, quando fecho e executo o `JFrame` novamente, o LAF escolhido não permanece salvo.

Gostaria de saber como criar algum Método para que o LAF selecionado permanecesse aplicado ao reabrir o `JFrame`.

Aqui está o Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o Código de Botão Salvar:

```
private void btnSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // Acao de Botao Salvar
       String t = (String)jComboBoxLAF.getSelectedItem();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, t);

        try {

            if ("Metal".equals(t)){

                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MetalLookAndFeel());
                this.setVisible(false);
                new TelaJtable().setVisible(true);

            }else if("Nimbus".equals(t)){
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());
                this.setVisible(false);
                new TelaJtable().setVisible(true);

            }else if("CDE/Motif".equals(t)){
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MotifLookAndFeel());
                this.setVisible(false);
                new TelaJtable().setVisible(true);

            }else if("Windows".equals(t)){
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new WindowsLookAndFeel());
                this.setVisible(false);
                new TelaJtable().setVisible(true);
            }
            else if("Windows Classic".equals(t)){
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new WindowsClassicLookAndFeel());
                this.setVisible(false);
                new TelaJtable().setVisible(true);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }            
    }
```

Comment: Você está salvando num arquivo externo? Esta é a unica forma de fazer isso. usando o construtor de GUI do netbeans, o tema inicial sempre será Nimbus, a não ser que você crie um mecanismo para salvar a opção escolhida num arquivo externo, e verifique-a antes da tela ser aberta.

Comment: Ola diegofm obrigado pela sua resposta, me desculpe talvez seja a minha explicação mal explicada, Não no arquivo externo, eu quero salvar a opção do LAF/Tema selecionado do tipo quando executar o JFrame novamente mudar pra outro LAF escolhido anteriormente, para não ter que sempre  selecionar o LAF todas as vezes que executar o JFrame! uma vez que a ação de botão "salvar" que eu criei só apenas Altera o LAF para outro, mas a opção não fica salvo, tenho que selecionar todas as vezes.

Comment: Foi o que eu disse, não tem jeito de fazer isso sem salvar num arquivo externo. Após encerrar o programa, ele é despejado da memória, nada é salvo(caso você não tenha programado nenhum tipo de persistencia de dados). Tem como definir um tema padrão que sempre será usado ao abrir(como o netbeans já faz com o nimbus), só isso. Qualquer mudança disso, precisa de arquivo externo.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez diegofm, Opa não tenho ideia como fazer isso, podes me dar uma orientação para poder salvar num arquivo externo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com um simples arquivo de texto, salvando o nome do LAF¹(ou o nome da classe inteira) quando alterar o LAF¹ dentro da aplicação, e carregando este arquivo ao abrir a aplicação para checar qual tema foi salvo.

Uma das formas que eu sempre uso quando preciso desse tipo de recurso é usar a classe [**`Properties`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), onde posso salvar vários itens de configuração e recuperá-los mais facilmente do que fazendo isso fazendo a leitura tradicional de um arquivo de texto.

Para o seu caso, eu fiz um exemplo de classe chamada `Propriedade`, cuja função  é ler e salvar o LookAndFeel da sua aplicação de um arquivo `config.properties`. Este último você pode trocar por qualquer nome(ex. config.txt).

```
public static class Propriedade {

    private static Properties prop;
    //aqui você pode mudar o nome e a extensão do arquivo
    private static String path = "config.properties";

    private static void LoadPropertiesFile() throws IOException {
        prop = new Properties();
        File f = new File(path);

        if (f.isFile()) {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(f);
            prop.load(file);
        } else {
            //se o arquivo não existir, cria um novo
            f.createNewFile();
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(f);
            prop.load(file);
            //seta um valor inicial em branco pro parametro do LAF
            // isso é para evitar NullPointerException ao chamar
            // getLookAndFeel() logo após criar o arquivo
            setLookAndFeel("");
        }
    }

    public static String getLookAndFeel() throws IOException {
        LoadPropertiesFile();
        return prop.getProperty("lookandfeel.name");
    }

    public static void setLookAndFeel(String name) throws IOException {
        LoadPropertiesFile();
        prop.setProperty("lookandfeel.name", name);
        prop.store(new FileOutputStream(path), "");
    }
}
```

Para usar, você só precisa invocar um dos dois métodos públicos(a classe já está criando o arquivo se ele não existir).

Apenas lembrando que se você chamar o `getLookAndFeel()` antes de abrir sua tela, é importante verificar se o valor retornado é nulo ou em branco, pois se a classe acabou de criar o arquivo, o valor retornado será em branco(como pode ser viso no método`LoadPropertiesFile()`), ou se alguém mudar os valores diretamente no arquivo, pode retornar nulo também.

> Obs.: conforme dito nos comentários, este método só ira funcionar corretamente com os look and feel's que estiverem instalados, se estiver usando algum externo ao java, você precisa instalar eles através do método `UIManagerr.installLookAndFeel(String name, String className)`, onde `name` é um nome "amigável" do LAF¹, e `className` é o nome da classe, ficaria algo assim: `installLookAndFeel(String "Custom LAF¹", String "com.example.mycustomlaf")`.

---

Para exemplificar, veja um exemplo executável do funcionamento desta classe:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 *
 * @author diego.felipe
 */
public class SaveLAFTest {

    private void start() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Frame principal");
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JComboBox comboLAF = new JComboBox();

        for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            comboLAF.addItem(info.getName());
        }

        comboLAF.addItemListener(e -> {

            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                String LAFSelected = (String) e.getItem();
                changeLookAndFeel(LAFSelected);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
            }

        });

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(comboLAF);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void changeLookAndFeel(String name) {
        for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if (info.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    Propriedade.setLookAndFeel(name);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String myLAF = Propriedade.getLookAndFeel();
            if (myLAF == null || myLAF.isEmpty()) {
                Propriedade.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getName());
            } else {

                for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if (myLAF.equalsIgnoreCase(info.getName())) {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new SaveLAFTest().start());
    }

    public static class Propriedade {

        private static Properties prop;
        private static String path = "config.properties";

        private static void LoadPropertiesFile() throws IOException {
            prop = new Properties();
            File f = new File(path);

            if (f.isFile()) {
                FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(f);
                prop.load(file);
            } else {
                f.createNewFile();
                FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(f);
                prop.load(file);
                setLookAndFeel("");
            }
        }

        public static String getLookAndFeel() throws IOException {
            LoadPropertiesFile();
            //lookandfeel.name é o nome que será salvo do parâmetro
            //você pode mudar pra outro, mas lembre de alterar também
            // no método setLookAndFeel()
            return prop.getProperty("lookandfeel.name");
        }

        public static void setLookAndFeel(String name) throws IOException {
            LoadPropertiesFile();
            prop.setProperty("lookandfeel.name", name);
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream(path), "");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no gif abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

<sup>*1 - LAF = look and feel*</sup>

Comment: Olá diegofm me ajudaste bastante, deu tudo certo, porem não pude expressar nenhum sentimento de gratidão conforme a regra que não nos permite se não me engano. mas aceitei a sua resposta como útil.
Porém tenho mais um probleminha aqui, gostaria de mais uma ajuda sua, tenho uma biblioteca extra de LAFs, como posso fazer para adicionar os LAFs extra junto aos LAFs disponíveis no código que criaste para mim?

Comment: Nome da Biblioteca: JTattoo-1.6.11.jar

Aqui estão os nomes de pacotes e Classes:
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtatoo.plaf.noire.NoireLookAndFeel");
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.acryl.AcrylLookAndFeel");
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.texture.TextureLookAndFeel");
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.smart.SmartLookAndFeel");

Comment: Eu tentei adicionar da seguinte forma no teu código lá no initComponents(); 
 for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) { 
           comboLAF.addItem(info.getName());
         }
//assim    comboLAF.addItem(new NoireLookAndFeel());
//asimm    comboLAF.addItem(new info("NoireLookAndFeel", NoireLookAndFeel.class.getName()));

Tentei de outras formas também,porem não adiantou em nada parece que não se faz assim, alguma dica?

Comment: @AméricoJorge Creio que você precise instalar os LAFS, utilizando o comando `installLookAndFeel(String name, String className)`, passando o nome 'amigável que você quer que seja chamada o LAF, e o endereço de sua classe(esse que você está tentando passar no código). Isso precisa ser feito com todos os LAFs customs ali no começo do `try`, depois, todos serão listados normalmente no combobox.

Comment: você é um profissional pra valer aqui, deu tudo certo! um forte abraço , ate mais..